# I am trying to check if the specified window is visible to the screen using Winapi but not sure how to approach when two windows are not overlapped

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, pywin32

What I am trying to do is combining the regions of the top windows and checking if the specified window is present in the region if it is then displaying result. It does not giving results very accurately. And also I have problem when windows are non-overlapped. Does any one have any idea how to overcome this situation.
`p` is the foreground process

```cpp
while (p != NULL)
{
    if (IsWindowVisible(p)) {
        if ((GetWindowLongPtr(p, GWL_STYLE) & WS_ICONIC) || GetWindowLong(p, GWL_EXSTYLE) & WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW) {
        }
        else
        {
            RECT a;

            if (GetWindowText(p, str, 255)) {

                if ((_wcsicmp(str, _T("Program Manager"))))
                {

                    GetWindowThreadProcessId(p, &proc_id);
                    proc_hnd = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, proc_id);
                    flag = GetProcessImageFileName(proc_hnd, proc_name, 1024);
                    wstring test(&proc_name[0]); //convert to wstring
                    string test2(test.begin(), test.end());
                    LOGGER->info(test2);
                    GetWindowRect(p, &a);

                    z = CreateRectRgn(a.left, a.top, a.right, a.bottom);
                    if (wcsstr(proc_name, L"chrome.exe")) {
                        RECT op;
                        GetWindowRect(p, &op);
                        HRGN j1 = CreateRectRgn(op.left, op.top, op.right, op.bottom);

                        CombineRgn(j1, j1, y, RGN_DIFF); emphasized text
                            CombineRgn(y, y, z, RGN_OR);    //combining the region
                        switch (GetRgnBox(j1, &a))
                        {
                        case NULLREGION:

                            LOGGER->info("null region");
                            break;
                        case SIMPLEREGION:
                            LOGGER->info("simple region");
                            break;
                        case COMPLEXREGION:
                            LOGGER->info("complex region");
                            break;
                        default:
                            LOGGER->info("default region");

                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CombineRgn(y, y, z, RGN_OR);  //combining the region
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
    p = GetWindow(p, GW_HWNDNEXT); //getting the next window
}
```

Comment: How do you define visible, if part of your window is overlapped by other windows, is it invisible?

Comment: yes it is visible. If we see any kind of content in the client area to the eye then it is  defined as Visible.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [`IsOverlapped` sample](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8a2031e4-424b-4295-a9c5-1cce0cea5013/how-to-consistently-check-if-running-window-is-obscured-by-other-windows?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues) here, but it is used to detect whether it is overlapped by any window. I modified this sample to check whether the window is visible:

```
BOOL IsVisible(HWND window)
{
    HWND hWnd = window;
    RECT thisRect;
    if (!IsWindowVisible(window))
        return FALSE;

    GetWindowRect(window, &thisRect);
    HWND explorer = FindWindow(L"Shell_TrayWnd", NULL);
    DWORD explorer_pid;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(explorer, &explorer_pid);

    HRGN hrgn_above = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);
    HRGN hrgn_window = CreateRectRgnIndirect(&thisRect);
    while ((hWnd = GetWindow(hWnd, GW_HWNDPREV)) != NULL)
    {
        DWORD pid;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pid);
        if (pid == explorer_pid || !IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
            continue;
        RECT rc = {};
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rc);
        HRGN hrgn_hWnd = CreateRectRgn(rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom);
        CombineRgn(hrgn_above, hrgn_above, hrgn_hWnd, RGN_OR);
        DeleteObject(hrgn_hWnd);
    }
    int ret = CombineRgn(hrgn_window, hrgn_window, hrgn_above, RGN_DIFF);
    DeleteObject(hrgn_above);
    DeleteObject(hrgn_window);
    if (ret != NULLREGION && ret)
        return TRUE;
    
    return FALSE;
}
```

Use `GetWindow` + `GW_HWNDPREV` to get the windows list above the `hWnd` in Z order.

Comment: thank you. But consider a situation where two windows are non-overlapping.  Does your solution gives visible or invisible?. I am not sure how combinergn works with  RGN_OR when two windows are non-overlapped.

Comment: When two windows are non-overlapping, the `RGN_OR` will get a region that contains both of windows' rectangle region.

Comment: does the RGN_OR leave the region between the two non-overlapping windows?

Comment: Yes, `RGN_OR` does not include the region between the two non-overlapping windows. You could use [`GetRegionData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getregiondata) to check the [`RGNDATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-rgndata).